# Complex radio buttons in Rails 3

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In rails 3, I need to implement a form as below image.

My Question is What is the good way to do it in rails. I need to get params[:complete_deal], params[:camcel_deal] as an array(eg: params[:complete_deal] = [ 1 ],  params[:cancel_deal] = [2, 4] and params[:dont_change] =[3])

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that you could do it like that with plain html, but you could see if you have any luck with html arrays like so: [is it possible to have double nested input tag arrays in html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978664/is-it-possible-to-have-double-nested-input-tag-arrays-in-html?rq=1)

You could have `<input type="radio" name="cancel_deal[]" value="#{row_id}" >` and it should create `cancel_deal = { 0 => 2, 1 => 4 }`. Then you could just loop through like `cancel_deal.each { |r| r.values.first.do_something }`

Comment: Okay, but I need to select only one option per row. This time, it won't work.

Comment: That makes sense. I guess it ungroups the radio buttons. What if you did `name='actions[]' value='complete/cancel/don't change'`. Perhaps explicitly put an index like `actions[i]`. Not sure if this would view all the radio buttons as one group though.