# jQuery validate plugin with nested arrays has unexpected results

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, validation

I am using the following jQuery validation plugin:

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

I am trying to validate a nested array "tax_percents[]" which is inside another array. It only validates the first value in the array. The odd part is, for the second field in the array it kind of validates it and gives an error message in field 1.

Here is a live demo showing the error:

http://blastohosting.com/jquery_validate_array_error/

I have the following document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.validate.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<form action="" method="post" id="theForm">
Location 1 Tax 1:
<input type="text" name="locations[1][tax_percents][]" />
<br /><br />

Location 1 Tax 1:
<input type="text" name="locations[1][tax_percents][]" />
<br /><br />
Location 2 Tax 2:
<input type="text" name="locations[2][tax_percents][]" />
<br /><br />

Location 2 Tax 2:
<input type="text" name="locations[2][tax_percents][]" />

<input type="submit" />
</form>

<script>
    $("#theForm").validate({
        rules: 
        {
            "locations[1][tax_percents][]":
            {
                number: true
            },
            "locations[2][tax_percents][]":
            {
                number: true
            }
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: You said: "The odd part is, for the second field in the array it kind of validates it and gives an error message in field 1."

  And I see the two inputs duplicated with the same name. That could be a reason...

Comment: Probably, this answer will help you a litte bit more.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978664/is-it-possible-to-have-double-nested-input-tag-arrays-in-html

Comment: I understand that I am allowed to have inputs with the same name. (Thats what I need on the server side, but it makes client side validation tricky)

Answer (score 0):

The library doesn't support this functionality of having things named the same and validate each input.