# Yii - cannot define a safe array of attributes for form submit

Tags: php, yii

I have a PHP form that need to submit a array of numbers, what we have in view:

```
<input type="text" id="ProductForm_sizeobj_1" name="ProductForm[sizeobj[1]]" value="13">
<input type="text" id="ProductForm_sizeobj_2" name="ProductForm[sizeobj[2]]" value="13">
<input type="text" id="ProductForm_sizeobj_3" name="ProductForm[sizeobj[3]]" value="13">
```

And I define in form class:

```
public $sizeobj = array();

public function rules() {
    return array(
        array('/** other attributes **/, sizeobj', 'safe')
    );
}
```

Since "Sizeobj" is a dynamic attribute and the size will growth more then 3, therefore I use array. However after form submitted the error throw as follow:

```
Failed to set unsafe attribute "sizeobj[1" of "ProductForm".
```

I believe I might using the wrong method to setup array attribute, or wrong rule, any advice? I'm new to Yii, any help is appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978664/is-it-possible-to-have-double-nested-input-tag-arrays-in-html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `name="ProductForm[sizeobj][1]"` instead of `name="ProductForm[sizeobj[1]]"`